# Excel VBA lock access db records via DAO for editing

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, dao

I have an Excel application I've developed and now want to store all of the data  in an Access file (rather than an Excel sheet).  I'm able to read data in and write data out, my issue has to do with handling concurrent users.  There's around 150-200 square images that when clicked open up a UserForm that is loaded with data.  Users are able to go in and edit any of that data so I want to make sure that two users are not editing a record at the same time.  Given the size of it I do not want to lock down the entire file, just the one record.  Everything I've read so far indicates that the record only locks while in .Edit, however I want to lock it as soon as the user opens the UserForm, then apply any edits they made and unlock it.

Here's where I'm at now with the code, the first three sections are where the main focus is with this:

```
Sub OpenDAO()
   Set Db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(Path, ReadOnly:=False)
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM AccessDB1 WHERE ID = 5" '& Cells(1, Rng.Column)
   Set Rs = Db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
End Sub
'==========================================================================
Sub CloseDAO()
On Error Resume Next
   Rs.Close
   Set dbC = Nothing
   Set Rs = Nothing
   Set Db = Nothing
End Sub
'==========================================================================
Function ADO_update(Target As Range)
   Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set dbC = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)

   'if no change exit function
   If Target.Value = oldValue Then GoTo 0

On Error GoTo trans_Err
    'begin the transaction
    DBEngine.BeginTrans
    dbC.Execute "UPDATE AccessDB1 SET Field1 = 5 WHERE ID= 5"
    DBEngine.CommitTrans dbForceOSFlush
Exit Function

trans_Err:
   'roll back the transaction
   Workspaces(0).Rollback
0
End Function
'==========================================================================
Function MakeSQLText(data As Variant)
   If (IsNumeric(data)) Then
       MakeSQLText = data
   Else
       MakeSQLText = "'" & Replace(data, "'", "''") & "'"
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: Row-level locking is not available for DAO per Microsoft, by design - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306435.  The article does describe you to use ADO in conjunction with DAO to accomplish this, though.

Comment: Personally I'd add a Boolean to the table holding the data defaulted to False. I'd then check that field is False before showing the form, if it's True then someone else is in the record and show a message box or something. If it's False, open the form and change the record to True. When it's closed, set it back to False.

Comment: @GavinP I thought of this too, but it could create problems if Excel crashed or the Boolean wasn't updated back.  At the very least it'd add maintenance to unlock records (some sort of timestamp that only allows the record to be locked for a certain amount of time)

Comment: I can't seem to get the row to lock using ADO and the Boolean option is a good idea aside from an Excel crash.  I'm thinking the best way might be to write the date/time in a field and then set it back to null once updated. Then when a user tries to edit the field I'll check if the date/time is within the past 15 minutes (default timeout for edit mode) and if so return a message that it's currently being edited.  Do you guys see any disadvantages to that method?

Comment: @Phillip Nope.  I was able to use the method in the link I provided, but only works for MDB files (which is not particularly helpful).  I couldn't get it to work with ADO either and don't really have time at the moment to mess with it more.  If I get a chance and figure it out, I'll make an answer.  You can leave the recordset in .Edit mode when the form is opened, but that was locking the whole table for me and not just the relevant row.  May be a way to set it to lock only the relevant record, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @OpiesDad I was able to get the date/time method to work, so for this project that will do.  Thanks for your help though